# Excluding some php-pages but not others with wget?

Tags: php, wget

I want to use `wget` to recursively download a website.  The site contains articles served by a php-script, eg. www.example.com/article.php?id=1021&ch=5 - these are what I want, all separate article with all chapters.

Unfortunately, the site also contains comments - lots and lots of comments.  Comments are also served by a php-script, eg. www.example.com/comment.php?id=1021&no=144 - these I absloutely *don't* want.

Basically, I want everything *except* the comments.  The problem is that links to articles, chapters and comments are interspersed on article-and chapter-lists, so there is no way to "fine tune" the level of recursion to avoid them... and doing level for level and manually sort-out between each, would take too much time and effort.

Since both are php-scripts, using the -A or -R options of wget to accept or reject files with a certain suffix won't work - or does it?  Are there any other more precise way to exclude one php-script but not others when downloading recursively?

Answer (score 2):

The following will provide some insight as to what you are looking for: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html

You should be able to use `--exclude /comment.php` to exclude all variations of the page `comment.php`